# Open RTFD file in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I am developing an application for IPhone. I have an RFTD file named Class01.rtfd in my project. I want to open it in UIWebView. But It is not working. My Code is as follows:

```
NSString *localFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Class01" ofType:@"rtfd"] ;
NSURLRequest *localRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                              [NSURL fileURLWithPath:localFilePath]] ;

[self.webview loadRequest:localRequest] ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display a rtfd file in a UIWebView you should compress it in a zip file, the file must keep both extension, for instance : Class01.rtfd.zip ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008749))

Comment: I love the way Apple create intuitive stuff.